# How to use the Google VR SDK 1.50 in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I Have just Updated My Unity 3D to 5.6 and I Have Also updated The Google VR SDK to 1.50 and Now the GvrViewerMain is No More it's changed to GvrEditorEmulator and I have referred the google docs for the help but I do not understand how to use the GvrEditorEmulator 
can anyone please tell me how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Unity 5.6 supports Google Cardboard natively, so you no longer need to use GvrViewerMain.

In the player settings, where you select to enable virtual reality you can add VR SDKs.

[image]

Comment: i Have enabled the cardboard SDK in the player settings ....but the problem starts when i add the GvrEditorEmulator in the hierarchy ...and when i add the GvrEditorEmulator and run the app the app doesn't start ...how to add the google VR view in the game

Comment: are you talking about running the app in the editor?

Comment: No I'm am talking about the app running in the android phone

Comment: Then there is no need for the GvrEditorEmulator as it is only used for emulating the cardboard view in the editor

Comment: i turned on the Virtual Reality supported and added the cardboard SDK and i run the app in the android phone but the app was forced stopped...How to Solve this

Comment: what do you mean by 'forced stopped'?